# POST not sent after jQuery form validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, modal-dialog

My form is defined within a Bootstrap modal and looks something like:

```
<form class="contact" name="contact" id="contact-form">
    <label class="modalLabel" for="name">Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="input-xlarge" minlength="2" required><br>
    <label class="modalLabell" for="email">E-mail Adresse</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge" required><br>
    <label class="modalLabel" for="message">Any message?</label><br>
    <textarea name="message" class="input-xlarge"></textarea>
    <div>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Absenden" id="submit">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Doch nicht</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

The jQuery for AJAX and validation:

```
$("#contact-form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form.contact).ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "process.php", //process to mail
                        data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                        success: function(msg){
                            $("#thanks").html(msg) //hide button and show thank you
                            $("#form-content").modal('hide'); //hide popup  
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert("Bitte versuchen Sie es nochmal.");
                        }
            });
        }
});
```

I got the AJAX working without the validation by putting the `$.ajax` call in a `click()` function. After I added the validation with the jQuery plugin, the POST doesn't work anymore. It seems like a GET is done at the moment and I don't know how to get this working.

Comment: is it  `$('form.contact')` or  `$(form.contact)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(form.contact).ajax({...` is likely  throwing an error because there is no selector specific ajax method and there is no object `form.contact`. For a class selector it would need quotes around `form.contact`

Try changing to

```
$.ajax({...
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the working sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbewGp

```
$("#contact-form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php", //process to mail
                    data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#thanks").html(msg) //hide button and show thank you
                        $("#form-content").modal('hide'); //hide popup  
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("Bitte versuchen Sie es nochmal.");
                    }
        });
    }
```

});